# How can I control button margins using CSS (IE8 compatible)

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer-8, styles

I am trying to style buttons so that the margins to the left/right of the text are much smaller than default style.

*Example:*

[image]

**How can I do that using CSS that is compatible with IE8?**

I tried this but didn't work (line breaks are only for MarkDown's sake):

```
<button style="font-size=11px;
margin-right:1px;padding-right:1px;margin-left:1px;padding-left:1px;">
Copy parameters to another fund</button>
```

I know I can tweak this by setting the `width` attribute, but for that I'd have to set individual with for every single different text which isn't scalable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to include a doctype.  This works for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<button style="font-size=11px;
      margin-right:1px;padding-right:1px;margin-left:1px;padding-left:1px;">
        Copy parameters to another fund
    </button>
</body>
```

Actually, you don't need the margins, padding will do.